# How should a NAS based Load Balanced Environment be configured in Umbraco?

Tags: iis, umbraco, load-balancing, nas

I'm currently running Umbraco 4.7.1.1.  I'm working on setting up a NAS based Load Balanced Environment and I'm wondering if I need to setup a "TEMP" virtual directory, see ***Reference**, to handle the ClientDependency and ExamineIndexes files IN ADDITION to setting `<add key="umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp" value="true" />`.

I understand that `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp = true` tells the logic to place/use the umbraco.config file in the ASP.Net temp folder local to the individual server.  I've been running into performance issues if I only have `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp = true` in place.  The issues appear to go away when I have the virtual directory in place (pages load twice as fast).  I'm starting to lean towards not using `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp = true` and to store all of it in the virtual directory using `<add key="umbracoContentXML" value="~/App_Data/TEMP/umbraco.config" />`.  I would prefer to not have to use a virtual directory.

I started setting up my load balanced environment using: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/installing-umbraco-for-load-balanced-environments which now contains a link that redirects you to http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/load-balancing. This document seems to indicate that I can optionally use a virtual directory if I'm using File Storage with File Replication.  It seems to indicate that `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp = true` is all that you need to use for File Storage witha NAS.

I believe that http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/installing-umbraco-for-load-balanced-environments used to contain the same content as this: http://our.sandbox.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/installing-umbraco-for-load-balanced-environments. This document seems to indicate that you need to have a virtual directory in place but it does not even reference `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp`.

-----------------------------

***Reference**

In addition to enabling the distributed calls above, there are some additional items that should be modified as well.  Each server will need a unique copy of the /App_Data/TEMP directory for Examine and Client Dependency Cache to work correctly.  Further, the umbraco.config xml cache file should also be unique to limit any issues with file locks.

#### Configuring Temp files with a virtual directory

1. Edit **/web.config** and change the **umbracoContentXML** to use **~/App_Data/TEMP/umbraco.config**.
2. Copy the **/App_Data/TEMP** directory to each server, outside of any replication areas or to a unique folder for each server.
3. Create a **virtual directory** (not a virtual application) in the **/App_Data** folder, and name it **TEMP**.  Point the virtual directory to the folder you created in step 2.
4. You may delete the **/App_Data/TEMP** folder from the file system (not IIS as this may delete the virtual directory) if you wish.

Comment: What kind of performance difference are you getting? When using `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp = true`, is it like they pages are starting up for the first time, each time? Or are they just sluggish, and using a virtual directory is quicker?

Comment: Also, are you running the test on the loadbalanced domain, or an individual, non-loadbalanced subdomain for the individual server?

Comment: I'm calling each server individually.  I loaded the same page 10 times and then I recorded the next 5 page loads.

Server 1 (Virtual Directory in place)
0.33, 0.35, 0.36, 0.35, 0.36

Server 2 (No Virtual Directory)
2.04, 2.10, 1.08, 2.06, 2.14

The servers are identical but just to be safe I'll try placing the virtual directory on the other server and I'll reply with my findings.

Comment: I placed the virtual directory on Server 2 and removed it from Server 1.  The results were what I expected to see.  Server 2 is now fast and Server 1 is now slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using DFS Replication instead of a NAS solution.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using NAS is so that you don't necessarily need virtual directories. There is one shared file repository for all instances of the CMS. Because everything is stored in one place you don't need file replication either but you do have to ensure that the backoffice has sole access to it.

The exception is umbraco.config. This file needs to be present per instance and so you have to set `umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp = true`. This allows the umbraco.config file to be created in the `HttpRuntime.CodegenDir` directory (the directory where ASP.NET stores temporary files).

If you are noticing a substantial difference in performance between this and using a virtual directory *instead*, it is possibly because you don't have write permissions to the `HttpRuntime.CodegenDir` directory (so what is happening is that the site is hitting the database for its content each time).

Check these permissions first, as this option should be as quick as using a virtual directory, and less maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I double checked and the app pool user has full rights to the asp.net temp files. I can see the web.config file being created/updated within HttpRuntime.CodegenDir when I publish content changes.  Do you have any more ideas on anything I should review?

Comment: Did you mean umbraco.config? This is the file that should be created by Umbraco in the HttpRuntime.CodegenDir folder at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I meant to say umbraco.config in my previous comment.